# Implicit cast doesn't work for BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF and BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading, boost-spirit

I have defined a boost::spirit::qi rule:

```
boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, Identifier()> id;
```

where Identifier is defined by:

```
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(std::string, Identifier)
```

but when I use

```
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(id);
```

It fails to compile with following error:

```
boost_1_51_0/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:1203: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'out << val'
```

and it lists the overloaded operators of ostream.

Knowing that BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF defines a cast operator to the original type, shouldn't
compiler implicitly cast from Identifier to std::string when using `operator<<`? or is there a restriction that prevents compiler to apply a cast operator of a type when it is trying to match the other operator (namely `operator<<` )?

When I define the following operator it compiles:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Identifier& id)
{
    return os << static_cast<std::string const&>(id);
}
```

I am using gcc4.4.2

Comment: Always make that `static_cast<std::string const&>` of course. Senseless copying occurs otherwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with boost, strong_typedef or spirit.

It has a lot to do with type deduction for template arguments. In short, when argument types are deduced, implicit conversions *never* take place [1]

Cf.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/strong_typedef.hpp>

BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(double, X)
int main() { std::cout << X(); }
```

No problem! Replace `double` by `std::string`, and it doesn't work anymore. What's different?

The declaration of the streaming operator differs.

Contrast

```
ostream& ostream::operator<<(double);
```

To

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
   inline basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
   operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> const&)
```

The fact that the operator overload is a *function template* disallows any implicit conversions.

---

[1] I guess `initializer_list` may look like a bit of an exception here, what with widening/narrowing that it can do. Different subject, though

Comment: I have found an example in the c++98 standard that is conflicting with what you have mentioned IMHO. But I might have misunderstood. look at http://nepsweb.co.uk/langstand/isoCPP/ISO14882/template.html. Section 14.8.3 example 4. A sub type is being casted to a base type reference. The question is if the statement "The fact that the operator overload is a function template disallows any implicit conversions." is true, then why according to the standard an implicit cast to the base reference type is allowed?

Comment: @amirmonshi That's not a cast. It's just a polymorphic reference to the same object (the same object _identity_ in OO speak)

Comment: Isn't it called upcast? But I think I understand what you mean. The operator is really a conversion, where compiler needed to have taken extra care for when deducing the template type but upcast to the base reference is somehow "automatic".

Comment: I think the correct word is: static. Derived is-a Base. This relation is statically known. With multiple inheritance, it ***is*** possible to get into places where an 'up-cast' (misnomer?) is actually ambigiuous. This is when you'll have to specify an explicit cast in the calling code. See also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7197887/85371