# Access Individual classes of a derived class, which is derived from two same base class

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I have a *base class* called `Number`. Class `One` and `Two` are derived from `Number`.
Now I define another class `Three`, where I need to access individual base classes from the *multiple inheritance*:

```
class Number{
  protected:
     int val;
  public:
    Number(){
        val=0;
    }
    void Add(Number n){//Receives another Number class instance and add the value
        val+=n.val;
    }
};

//class One derived from Number
class One:public Number{
  public:
     One(){
          cal=1;
     }
};

//class two derived from Number
class Two:public Number{
  public:
     Two(){
          val=2;
     }
};

class Three:public One,public Two{
  public:
     Three(){
          Two::Add(One);//--How can i pass instance of class One Here
     }
};
```

**I tried One::Number and Two::Number, but no use.**

Comment: `Add(One)`, `One` is not an instance of your class, but the type itself. You  need a variable of type `One`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Two::Add(*(One*)this);
```

Comment: I originally posted a hint to the type conversion as a comment, but you have to realize there are serious issues that remain regarding your class design when you solve it like this.

Comment: @DyP There are legitimate use cases where a base class is inherited twice. This is obviously a simplified example and it's impossible to tell whether the real design has "serious issues".

Comment: @Henrik Considering the level of the question I think it is unlikely that is what is intended and the implications should at least be noted.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems, first `val` is private and so that needs to be made `protected`. Next you have a [diamond of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137282/how-can-avoid-the-diamond-of-death-in-c-if-i-use-multiple-inheritance) so you need to `virtual public` for `One` and `Two`. You also are trying to call `Add` using a `type` but you need an `instance` of each class:

```
class Number{
protected:
     int val;
public:
    Number(){
        val=0;
    }
    void Add(Number& n){//Receives another Number class instance and add the value
        val+=n.val;
    }
};

//class One derived from Number
class One:virtual public Number{
public:
     One(){
          val=1;
    }
};

//class two derived from Number
class Two:virtual public Number{
public:
     Two(){
          val=2;
     }
};

class Three: public  One,  public  Two{
public:
     Three()
     {
           Two t1 ;
           Add(t1 );//--How can i pass instance of class Two Here
     }
};
```

It could be argued that using `protected` data is bad but it depends [on your case](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/protected-data-not-evil.html) but to be complete it is also a choice to keep `val` a `private` data member and use a `protected constructor` and that would look like this:

```
class Number{
private:
     int val;
protected:
   Number( int n ) : val(n) {} 
public:
    Number(){
        val=0;
    }
    void Add(Number& n){//Receives another Number class instance and add the value
        val+=n.val;
    }
};

class One: virtual public Number{
public:
     One() : Number( 1 ) {

     }
};

class Two: virtual public Number{
public:
     Two() : Number(2) {
     }
};
```

Comment: I wouldn't make `val` protected for the sole purpose to set it in the ctor. You can as well create a protected ctor `Number::Number(int)`.

Comment: @DyP I believe it depends on your use case but I amended my answer to cover both and the issues around that.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create objects of the respective types.

```
class Three : public One, public Two
{
public:
     Three()
     {
          Add(One());
          Add(Two());
     }
};
```

But I don't see why you need MI here. Inheriting from Number would be sufficient.

Comment: I edited the question, I need to use Add function of One or Two to add the other.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not just the syntax. But what exactly are you trying to do?

You can. But where is the instance of `One` declared? you have to declare it first. Remember `Two::Add(One);` is not a declaration rather a call statement.

What you are doing is equivalent to let's say

```
process_number(One);
```

Where process number is a function.