# Avoiding a diamond inheritance

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, diamond-problem

I have a class `A`.

classes `B` and `C` are interfaces that derives from class `A`.

```
      A
    /   \
   B     C
```

now I have to implement the classes `D` and `E` for both `B` and `C`.

and then there are some classes: `FDB`, `GDC`, `HEC`, `IEB`, `JDB`, `KDC`, `LEB`, `MEC` (while `DB` and `DC` in the end of the name of these classes means that the class uses `D` and `B` for the ending of `DB`, `D` and `C` for `DC`, `E` and `B` for `EB`, etc..

so:

```
class A..

class `B`: public virtual `A`..
class `C`: public virtual `A`..

class `D`: public B, public `C`..
class `E`: public B, public `C`..

class `FDB`: public `D`..
class `GDC`: public `D`..
class `HEC`: public `E`..
class `IEB`: public `E`..
class `JDB`: public `D`..
class `KDC`: public `D`..
class `LEB`: public `E`..
class `MEC`: public `E`..
```

but then I have a diamond inheritance and I don't want it.

can someone suggest another design please?

any help appreciated!

Comment: Can I ask **why** you don't want it? This could be what **virtual inheritance** is for.

Comment: Possible answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137282/how-can-avoid-the-diamond-of-death-in-c-if-i-use-multiple-inheritance).

Comment: Oh dear lord. Really? All those abbreviations....

Comment: If you tell us why you need it, maybe we show a solution to solve the problem indirectly, I think there is not a real application which needs this issue.

Comment: @MM. there are some neat applications of virtual inheritance and most derived subtleties and all that, e.g. to emulate named template parameters (there's a nice section on that in Vandevoorde & Josuttis). But you are absolutely right: mortal user code should stay away from such huge class hierarchies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the reason you want/need to avoid multiple inheritance?

Either way, if you cannot (do not want to) use inheritance in some of these cases, use encapsulation:

```
class A..

class `B`: public virtual `A`..
class `C`: public virtual `A`..

class `D`: public B {
private:
    C c_instance_;
};
class `E`: public B {
    C c_instance_;
};

...
```

To avoid code duplication, you can create a C (or D) holder and inherit it through protected inheritance and CRTP. This way a separate base class holds the C base functionality but the classes that inherit from it do not have a common base class:

```
class A..

class B: public A..
class C: public A..

template<class Specialized, class DependedOn>
class DependsOn {
protected:
    DependedOn& get() { return implementation_; }
private:
    DependedOn implementation_;
};

class D: public B, protected DependsOn<D, C> .. // inheritance with CRTP
class E: public B, protected DependsOn<E, C> .. // inheritance with CRTP

class FDB: public D, protected DependsOn<FDB, B> ..
```

`D`, `E`, `FDB` and so on, will use the `get()` method internally (or more specifically, `DependsOn<D, C>::get()`, `DependsOn<E, C>::get()` and so on) to implement the public interface.

Since `DependsOn<D, C>` is different from `DependsOn<E, C>`, you only have a common interface implemented by the whole hierarchy.