# A C++ issue with multiple inheritance, templates and static variables

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, static-variables

I have a code similar to the following:

```
template<class ObjType>
class jsonable
{
 private:
    static map<string, jsonElem> config;
 protected:
    virtual void setConfig() = 0;
 //other fields and methods in public/private
}

class user : public jsonable<user>
{
 protected:
    virtual void setConfig();
 //other fields and methods in public/private
}

class client : user
{
 protected:
    virtual void setConfig() {user::setConfig(); /* more config */}
 //other fields and methods in public/private
}
```

The main idea of this code is to save in static variables data related to the class referenced in the template. The problem comes when I want to inherit from the user class: the static variable is shared between user and client classes, instead of one static variable for each class.

I've tried to do something like:

```
class client : user, jsonable<client>
```

But a bunch of problems appeared (many methods with same name, and some other related to inherit 2 times the same class). I don't know if there is an elegant way of do this, or even if there is a way at all. (I'm a bit newbie in c++)

Any idea would be welcome! :). And of course, I can "copy" all the contents of user into client but... I would like to do not do that until there are no more options.

**Edit:**
In order to add context and details to the question, I'm going to explain a bit what I'm doing (or want to do).
Jsonable is a class that provides the ability to serialize into Json another class (helped by https://github.com/nlohmann/json).

To achive this, it uses a static map to store each jsonable-field name and its info (type and position relative to the start of the class in memory, so it can be serialized and deserialized).

The problem comes if a class inherits from another class that inherits from jsonable. Both shares that map, so only the baseclass data is consider when serializing/deserializing. Hope this explanation helps to understand...

**Edit2**: Giving a full code in a question seems very overkilling to me. If someone wants something to compile, I've uploaded a git repo: https://github.com/HandBe/jsontests
Really thanks to all the people who have put interest on this question!.

Comment: Maybe a dupe, maybe not, but worth a read all the same:  [How can I avoid the Diamond of Death when using multiple inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137282/how-can-i-avoid-the-diamond-of-death-when-using-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question, if you explained what the desired behavior of your classes/subclasses is.

Comment: Why do you want `client` to be a jsonable client when it's already a jsonable user through `user` ?

Comment: Thank you guys, i added an small explanation to the question so it the problem can be more understable. Hope I hope not to bore anyone. @user4581301 i'm going to check it and virtual inheritage, thanks!

Comment: If you can implement `user` without deriving from `jsonable<user>`, it will be easy to resolve your problem.

Comment: Please make sure you don't forget the virtual ~dtors in your actual code.

Comment: @RSahu Well... that made me think... Is there a way to do something like:
`template<class upperClass = user>
class user : public json::jsonable<upperClass>` ? First try seems like an infinite description-recursion

Comment: No, that won't work. I was thinking you can use `json::jsonable<user>` in the implementations of the member functions of `use` that depend on the functionality provided by `json:jsonable`.

Comment: Can't debug invisible code. Please demonstrate a specific problem that can be reproduced by others, as described in [mcve].

Comment: Where do you use `ObjType`? If it's not used, then the whole problem disappears into an abstract discussion of not-happening problems.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code though it might result in quite a convoluted interface. I agree with comments above, we need the context in which this code is used.

Comment: One problem could be, that `jsonable<A>` and `jsonable<B>` are different classes, so you can't rely on virtual inheritance to solve any duplication issues with this design.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your interest.
I've uploaded to github a full-compilable example of this with one of the modifications suggested bellow. Of course it doesn't work (yet) at runtime, but I expect it could make the context more understable... if not, I don't know how to be more explicit without a big-big question :/
Git repo: https://github.com/HandBe/jsontests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution can be derive `client` from both `user` (because it is a user) and `jsonable<client>` as (private/public apart)

```
class user : public jsonable<user>
{
 protected:
    virtual void setConfig();
 //other fields and methods in public/private
};

class client: public user, public jsonable<client>
{
   virtual void setConfig()
   {
       user::setConfig();
       // more config, referred to jsonable<client>::map
   }
}
```

because it has to implement jsonable for itself (regardless of `user`).

This is the so-called "stacked parallelogram" inhertiance pattern very common in multiple interface implementations as modular behavior.

Now user and client have each their own configuration

Comment: I've been working in it for a half-day or so. I'm still on it, since it seems the best option (of course like @grek40 said it doesn't work with virtual inheritance, but i believe something can be done). The actual state with this implementation: https://github.com/HandBe/jsontests

Comment: it finally worked! I've to add many workaround like a new function `virtual void setConfig(map<string, json::jsonElem> &config)` to pass the static to base class, so base-class can "register" its information inside the upper-class info. Thank you!
PD: Probably, i'll make this opensource when it's full-verifyed. Thank you all ~ !

Comment: It must NOT work with virtual inheritance: `jasonable<user>` and `jasonable<client>` are distinct things that must not be merged (and cannot be)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly: you want `client` to be a `user`, but also have all the per-class statics defined in `jsonable`?

Have you considered composition over inheritance? This could work either way:

1) make `user` a component of client

```
class client : public jsonable<client>
{
    user parent; // could also be a pointer
    void setConfig() {parent.setConfig(); /* more config */}
    /* ... */
}
```

2) make `jsonable` a component:

```
class user
{
    jsonable<user> userjson; // public, private, whatever is appropriate for your design
    /* ... */
}

class client : public user
{
    jsonable<client> clientjson;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Joris. Of course I've considered it, and of course it can be the final option. The problem of this implementation is that i cant create a list of different users. Of course, if i don't find any better option, i would take it!