# base class ambiguous when converting derived class pointer to base class

Tags: c++

I'm using C++. When I try to convert a derived class' pointer to base class', compiler complains "base class is ambiguous".

I did some research, and found this question [How can I avoid the Diamond of Death when using multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137282/how-can-i-avoid-the-diamond-of-death-when-using-multiple-inheritance). And some other similar issue.

There is a solution, is to use `virtual inheritance`. But I'm not able to change class definitions, because they are compiled libraries.

Is that possible to do the converting, without changing base class definitions?

A minimal sample would be:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};
class D : public B, public C {};
```

What I want to do is:

```
D *d = new D;
A *a = (D *)d;  // ambiguous
```

Comment: How did you end up with such a design? Diamond inheritance is frowned upon for this very reason.

Comment: The problem is a conceptual one. You don't just "convert pointers" in some opaque, magical way. What you're really doing is obtaining the address of a base subobject from a more derived object. Once you realize that, and the fact that you may have multiple base subobjects of the same type, the solution becomes clear.

Comment: I'm maintaining an ancient project, makes it impossible to modify base classes.

Comment: It would be better if you'd provide a minimal code that illustrated a problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is that possible to do the converting, without changing base class definitions?

Yes it is. You have to choose which direct base class to go through.

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};
class D : public B, public C {};

void foo(A&) {}

int main() {
    D d;

    foo(static_cast<B&>(d));
    foo(static_cast<C&>(d));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MartinZhai, glad I helped. Figured it should be an answer. But seriously, see if you can update the base classes. You may be surprised for the better.

Comment: That would be a better solution, and this one is good enough for now.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do this converting, a little tricky though.

Following code would do the job:

```
A *a = (B *)d;
```

Comment: "(B *)d" can you explain it? I know " * B " what does it mean , but this is confusing

Comment: @imtithal This is to explicitly convert `d` to pointer of `B` first. Then compiler will implicitly convert pointer of `B` to pointer of `A` (not ambiguous anymore since `B` has only one parent class).