# What to do when a class doesn’t need to override a method inherited from multiple bases?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, overriding

I m learning inheritance using C++.If I have a class A , and I have inherited class B and C from A, further I have derived class D from B and C (classical diamond problem).
If I have a virtual function print() in A , I overloaded it in B and C, but not in D.
Now, if I have an object of class D and I call print(), it would be an error.
Is there any useful way to avoid this error?

Comment: Please [show](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48489540/edit) the relevant code instead of describing it. Diamond problem and multiple inheritance are things often rehashed by academia. Industry deals with other kind of problems.

Comment: Simple solution to the so called _diamond problem_ is: don't use multiple inheritance.

Comment: someone just please tell our teachers:-p

Comment: Strongly related:[How can I avoid the Diamond of Death when using multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137282/how-can-i-avoid-the-diamond-of-death-when-using-multiple-inheritance). Helpful reading: [Inheritance — Multiple and Virtual Inheritance](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance) and [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override the method in `D`, even if it is just to forward to one (or both) of the `B` and `C` overrides.  (You have to do this even if you never call `print` on an expression whose static type is `D`, since an `A*` elsewhere could point to a `D`.)

Comment: means there is no other way around!