# I have a variable b in parent class and when i try to access variable b from sum3 class it shows ambiguous b error

Tags: c++, inheritance, diamond-problem

I have a variable b in the parent class and when I try to access variable b from sum3 class it shows an ambiguous b error. And if I remove the sum from inheritance it will give "clas.cpp|25|error: 'int sum::b' is inaccessible within this context| " error what to do?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class sum
{

public:
int b=8;
};

class sum2:sum
{
public:
 int c=4;

};

class sum3:sum2,sum
{
 public:
int h=9;
 void add()
   { 
    int l;
    l=h+c+b;
    cout<<l;
   }
};

int main()
{
  sum3 c;
  c.add();
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because you are inheriting from both `sum2` and `sum` classes but `sum2` is inheriting from `sum` so it inherits the variable **b** also so when you intend to use the variable **b** inside of the class `sum3` the compiler doesn't know which variable you want because there is one in class `sum2` and one in class `sum` with the same name **b**.

one of the solutions to this is to use the scope resolution operator inside of the class `sum3` like this:

```
    class sum3:sum2,sum
{
 public:
int h=9;
 void add()
   { 
    int l;
    l=h+c+sum2::b;
    cout<<l;
   }
};
```

this removes the ambiguity by telling the compiler which variable I intend to use and in this case it's `sum2` variable.

**Note that:**

this is called the diamond problem and it occurs in multiple inheritance situations if you want to read further and to know how to avoid them you can use this link: [How can I avoid the Diamond of Death when using multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137282/how-can-i-avoid-the-diamond-of-death-when-using-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: Yes have an upvote. This is a perfectly legitimate way of disambiguating and I'm a bit naughty to present my answer as the only way.

Comment: @Bathsheba no problem at all, have a nice day!

Comment: BTW, Bathsheba shows the diamond whereas you keep the Y-form.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write

```
class sum2 : virtual sum
```

and

```
class sum3 : sum2, virtual sum
```

In this way you get only one `b` in `sum2` and `sum3`, so obviating the ambiguity.

More details at [In C++, what is a virtual base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class#21607)